# Seeding record is always included in every migration

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have created a syntax wherein it automatically adds a record in the table Roles (for example only). the syntax can be seen below.

```
public static void SeedRole(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasData(
        new Role
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Rolename = nameof(EnumList.Roles.Administrator)
        },
        new Role
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Rolename = nameof(EnumList.Roles.BayFront)
        },
        new Role
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Rolename = nameof(EnumList.Roles.FrontDesk)
        },
        new Role
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Rolename = nameof(EnumList.Roles.Kitchen)
        },
        new Role
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Rolename = nameof(EnumList.Roles.Manager)
        }
        );
}
```

And in the DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.SeedRole();
}
```

However, the problem is - every time I add a new migration, it always gets included in the migration file. Is there any way to avoid this?

Especially that the records got already added in the database (from earlier migrations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Guid.NewGuid()` in `HasData` method, because EF can not compate dynamic Ids. You need to generate Guids manually by youself and use it like `new Guid("9abbf48f-5fc3-4bc2-8f7b-0d7acdc8dc00")`